# how to use regex to split a format string?

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to split some string like this `@key='value'` to key and value.

my regex is `[^@'=]+[^'=]`, the output is good when the length of key and value is > 1, but sometimes when the length is only 1 char, the output is not correct.

Can anybody suggest improvements for my regex?

Comment: Please provide sample input and source code which fails.

Comment: @class='x' only output match class, the value x didn't output. But if @class='x1', the output match is class and x1

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing how that regex would match anything like your string... Examples, please! Both working and not working.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what your regex is doing. Why not just use `[^@'=]+` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to *capture* the key and value, you might try this:

```
/^@([^=]+)='([^']+)'$/
```

Then you will have the key in $1 and the value in $2.

**EDIT:**

I think I see what you're doing.  Change your regex simply to `[^@'=]+` to see the difference.  However we can't tell help you unless you tell us what language you're using and some sample code.

Comment: Got it, the first reply for me, I just need adjust my code. thanks all give suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
^@[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*=\s*'[A-Za-z0-9\s]+'

This captures 
@Key = 'value'
@key='value' 
@k = 'value'

etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\A@([^=]+)='([^']+)'
```

will work as the regex but it doesn't take into account escaping of the apostrophe.  this is 2 capture groups... \A says start of string... then @ then group.... (not= one or more) =' Group( not ' ) followed by '